# Проблема с TextBox

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. На C#_e из сервера получаю данные и хочу вводить на экран в textbox'е так

```
textbox.Text = allData.ToString();
```

результат такой - `System.Collections.ArrayList`. Подскажите, как исправить, чтобы нормальный текст выходила? Тип данных, которые выходят из сервера integer.

Comment: У Вас переменная типа ArrayList, а Вы пытаетесь ее в TextBox затолкать. Преобразуйте данные из ArrayList'a, хотя бы с помощью string.Join

Comment: Повтор вопроса
http://hashcode.ru/questions/112940/c-textbox-text?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=112945#112945

Answer (score 2):

Под рукой нет студии, но вроде можно так:

```
textBox.Lines = allData.ToArray();
```